# Retrieving root element from schema

Tags: java, parsing, xsd, saxparser, xsd-validation

i have a valid xsd and i want to retrieve the root element without using DOM library.
Is it possible with SAX or by programmatically parsing the file ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If your input is the XSD itself, it is not possible in general to identify the root element because there could be multiple global element definitions, and there is no XSD designation particular to the root element.

If your input is an XML document instance that is valid against the XSD, yes, you can determine the root element.  XML document instances that are valid are necessarily well-formed, and well-formed XML document instances have a single root element.  You mention SAX parsers.  The root element of a document instance will be the first element encountered.